# Event handler sometimes doesn't fire C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm working on a project with some event handling code. Basically, I create a timer and then tack on my own event handler for the timeout event. I double-checked by putting a break-point there and yes, the event handler does get added to that Event (yes, I also start the timer). For some reason, though, sometimes the event handler fires and at other times it does not. I'm using multi-threading, and have considered that it might be somehow related to that but am unsure.

I'm aware this is a vague question, but hoping that someone ran into something similar.

Thanks,

PM

EDIT: I have looked into the issue a bit further, and I notice that this is indeed a thread issue. The thread that is responsible for this event, is the one handling the network part of my program, and it blocks immediately after, because it is waiting for input from another instance of the program on the network. How would I get around this?

Comment: What timer has a timeout event?

Comment: Sanity check: when do you start (`myTimer.Start()`) your timer, and are you sure it is started when you expect your event to fire?

Comment: @Joey: I guess the OP meant `Elapsed`.

Comment: How are you trying to fire that event? Are you sure about threads do not wait for some events? Please, give a bit more information =)

Comment: I meant Tick, yes the timer itself definitely starts, but then the thread that started it blocks, see the edit.

Comment: With the edit, it becomes more to the point to post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have looked into the issue a bit further, and I notice that this is indeed a thread issue. The thread that is responsible for this event, is the one handling the network part of my program, and it blocks immediately after, because it is waiting for input from another instance of the program on the network. How would I get around this?

Sounds like you (a) have a [`System.Windows.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) with a [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) set to a UI control, or are using (b) a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). Then, you block the UI thread with a network read - preventing the event from firing.

You have 2 options, either use a different thread for the network read or for the timer event. If you use a System.windows.Timers.Timer, then don't pass a [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx), and it will raise the event on a `ThreadPool` thread. Or, [async the network read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx).

Comment: Problem solved. I was using the Windows.Forms.Timer. When I switched to System.Timers.Timer, everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, is there anyway to raise my own, custom, events on a ThreadPool thread, like the Timer does, instead of blocking?

Comment: @user472875 - You can use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and raise your event that way. Or, cycle through each delegate and call BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of timer is it, and do you retain a reference to it? Is it possible that the timer is being garbage collected before it's due to fire? There's a warning about this in the docs for [`System.Windows.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

Comment: I have added the GC.KeepAlive to both timers, with no results. I am almost certain that this problem occurs because the thread that created the timer blocks immediately after.